# Populate Listbox from controller asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

I have Soap service and parse information from it successfully. But I can't understand:**How use my model to populate listbox in view from controller?**.

**Model**

```
public class BA 
    {
        public int PeriodId { get; set; }
        public SelectList Period { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

**View**

```
@model WebApplication.Models.BA
@using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
    ...
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.PeriodId, new SelectList(Model.Period, "Value", "Text"), new { SelectionMode = "Single" })
    @Html.Hidden("hPeriod")
```

**Controller**

```
public class BAController : Controller
{
  BA modelBA = new BA();
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
      Load_Periods();
      return View(modelBA);
  }
  public void Load_Periods()
  {
      ...
      modelBA.PeriodId =  Convert.ToInt32(idPeriod);
      modelBA.Period = new SelectList(namePeriod);
```

**modelBA.PeriodId** and **modelBA.Period** **can have many values**, so may be I must use IEnumerable or something else.

Comment: And if it help. Now I have this exception: The " expression" must evaluate to IEnumerable, if allowed multiple selections.

Comment: I think all you need is a 'Dictionary<int,List<period>>' to represent your model correctly. this is based on the assumption that you have 1-many relationship between **PeriodId** and **Period**

Comment: @PreetSing I rewrite code.
So, **in model** I have only 
`public Dictionary<int, string> Period { get; set; }`
**In controller** 
`modelBA.Period.Add(Convert.ToInt32(idPeriod), namePeriod);`
**In view**
`@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Period.Values, new SelectList(Model.Period, "Key", "Value"), new { SelectionMode = "Single" })`
But I have nullRef exception, I thing my dictionary is null

Comment: @PreetSingh, solved,tnx. I just add private field and rewrite Dictionary property for this field.

Comment: @ExtUser in your Model initialize the dictionary in the constructor of the model like 'Period = new dictionary<......." that way it would never be null